# How does the array should look like? Array exercise question

Tags: php

I am doing some exercises online, and I am stuck on understanding the beginning of the question, I am not going to put all exercise because I want to resolve them myself, I just want to be sure that I understand correctly the tasks.

> We have an array A with N elements. N is between [1,100] and
> each of the N elements of A is a number an integer between [-10,000,
> 10,000].

So if I understand that correctly the array should look like

```
$array = [
'-10000',
'-9980',
'-9960',
'-9940'
(...)
'9940'
'9960',
'9980',
'10000',
];
```

Please let me know if I think about it correctly.

Comment: Kind of. The array could have anywhere between 1 and 100 elements, and each element can be any number in the given range of values. Do not assume it is regularly distributed like your example.

Comment: The array _could_ look like that, but you shouldn't make the assumption that values are evenly spaced throughout the possible range, that the array is ordered in any way, or that there are no duplicates.

Comment: This seems to be `PHP` code, how is `c#` or `.net` related? Don't spam tags, this can lead to downvotes

Comment: @brombeer I remove the tags

Comment: I would say no, since all of your array elements are of type `string`, not of `number`/`integer`

Answer (score 2):

According to the exercise description,
the assumed array

- **Could have** 1 or 100 or any number between **1** and **100** elements (1 <= N <= 100).
- Each element (number) could be between **-10,000** and **10,000**.

Note: the array is not always sorted it can be like it:

```
$A = [
    -10000,
    1,
    -99,
    -98,
    -98,
    -98,
    1122,
    ...
];
```